# localizing polynomial ring on $fg$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k[x_1,..,x_n] = A$ be the polynomial ring over $k$, let $f,g\in A$, then we can consider $A_{fg}$ be the localization at $fg$, we can also localize $A$ at $f$ then furthur localize at $g$  denote it $(A_f)_g$. Is it possible to show that $$A_{fg} = (A_f)_g \tag{*}$$

I think it's correct, my proof is given any element in the RHS it is of the form $$\{\frac{p}{f^mg^n}\mid p \in A,\ m,n\ge 0\} $$

Assume $m \ge n$ then it also equals to $\frac{pg^{m-n}}{(fg)^m}\in A_{fg}$ therefore we see (*) holds.

I think my proof is not very satisfactory, is there better proof of (*)

Comment: This is an almost immediate consequence of the universal property of localization. You should not write as $A_{(fg)}$, with parentheses, since this notation is preserved for the construction of $\operatorname{Proj}$.

Comment: If possible can you show more detail? I still can't work it out.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something. Is it not supposed that you must localize at prime ideals? How do you localize at $fg$?

Comment: $\{f^ng^n\mid n\ge 0\}$ is a multiplicative set. @A. J. Pan-Collantes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intuitively, in any ring $fg$ is invertible iff both of $f$ and $g$ are invertible. Hence inverting $f$, then $g$ is the same as to invert $fg$ directly. Your approach is fine, and another way is to show that $A[1/f][1/g]$ satisfies the universal property used to define $A[1/(fg)]$. It's not hard, but annoying.

This seemingly innocent fact has actually caused a lot of trouble in formalizing algebraic geometry. In fact, the Lean community led by Kevin Buzzard discovered [this](https://www.ma.imperial.ac.uk/%7Ebuzzard/xena/pdfs/lftcm22_schemes.pdf#page=14) in the attempt to formalize the definition of scheme. So this is by no means trivial, at least not for computers.

Comment: thank you Just a user, that's cool